# run xpath from xquery against a database?

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing, xquery, basex

How do I run an `xpath` query from within an `xquery` script with the `basex` GUI?

successful `xpath` query of a database:
[image: xpath]

failed `xquery` attempt:
[image: xquery]

The simplest possible `xquery` code for this database:

```
thufir@dur:~/basex$ 
thufir@dur:~/basex$ cat db_list_items.xq 

let $db := db:open("list")

return root()/descendant::li/a/text()

thufir@dur:~/basex$
```

Not quite sure how to return results above.

error log from the `basex` GUI:

```
Error:
Stopped at /home/thufir/basex/db_list_items.xq, 4/12:
[XPDY0002] root(): no context value bound.
Compiling:
- pre-evaluate db:open(database[,path]) to document-node(): db:open("list") -> db:open-pre("list", 0)
- inline $db_0
- simplify gflwor
Optimized Query:
root()/descendant::li/a/text()
Query:
let $db := db:open("list") return root()/descendant::li/a/text()
Query plan:
<QueryPlan compiled="true" updating="false">
  <CachedPath type="text()*">
    <FnRoot name="root([node])" type="node()?"/>
    <IterStep axis="descendant" test="li" type="element()*"/>
    <IterStep axis="child" test="a" type="element()*"/>
    <IterStep axis="child" test="text()" type="text()*"/>
  </CachedPath>
</QueryPlan>
```

looking for simple query of this database using `basex`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like navigating a filesystem (or any other tree based structure), we need to know our place within that structure, in order to be able to use path expressions:

```sh
/home/logname/documents/work #> cd todo
/home/logname/documents/work/todo #>
```

How did the command line interpreter know, where to find the *todo* directory? It knew this, because, by convention, it assumed the context for the `cd` command to be the *current directory*, which is `/home/logname/documents/work`, in this case.

When you load a document/database into BaseX, it does the same for XPath expressions and also XQuerys, as long the context is clear. If you, for example, place a single dot `.` in the query editor, and then execute that query, it will give you back the whole document, since this is what `.` stands for: the *current context item*. Here, BaseX knows this context from the convention, that it executes, by default, queries against the currently loaded document, just like a command line interpreter assumes the current directory as the current context. One could say, that by loading the document/database, you `cd`'ed into the root of that document. So far so good...

As soon as you use XQuery, you are using a complete programming language, that allows for much more, than just querying single documents. You could query a whole bunch of documents within one script.

Take this (incomplete) code fragment:

```
let $db  := db:open("list")
let $db2 := db:open("list2")
```

If you now place queries the way you did, where do they go? Are they using `$db` as context or `$db2`?

What you need to do is to tell the processor about this. This can be done several ways:

1. in the **prolog** of your script: `declare context item := db:open("list");` (see also: [BaseX documentation on this](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/XQuery_3.0#Context_Item) and, very important, [read about the difference between "static context" and "dynamic context" here](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-30/#context)) to learn more about context, in general.
2. in the XPath expression itself:

```
let $db := db:open("list")
return $db/root()/descendant::li/a/text()
```

or, simplified:

```
let $db := db:open("list")
return $db//li/a/text()
```

or:

```
declare context item := db:open("list");

.//li/a/text()
```